# MaterialToolbar.onMenuItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

i am trying to implement a custom app bar, currently i have 1 activity and using the navigation component to access different Fragments.

no matter what i do, i cannot access the click listener for the items

here's my XML

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/timeline_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/timeline_toolbar"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/timeline_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

and here's the method used to get the listener event

```
private fun handleActionBar() {
    timeline_toolbar?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        when (it.itemId){
            R.id.search_action -> {
                //search clicked
                true
            }
            R.id.logout_action -> {
                //logout clicked
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

i have been following https://material.io/develop/android/components/app-bars-top
and i did implement the Theme with NoActionBar

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure you have set the toolbar to be your support action bar. In onCreate in your activity, add

```
Toolbar timeline_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.timeline_toobar);
setSupportActionBar(timeline_toolbar);
```

2. Override the onCreateOptionsMenu() in your activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

3. Move this code bit

```
timeline_toolbar?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        when (it.itemId){
            R.id.search_action -> {
                //search clicked
                true
            }
            R.id.logout_action -> {
                //logout clicked
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
```

to your onCreate in the same activity.
Note: I've coded in Java because I don't know Kotlin syntax very well.